# Decoding entire HTML entities at once

Tags: c#, vb.net, html-agility-pack, html-entities, urldecode

I want to decode HTML or texts. I used -with the same result- this functions:

- HtmlEntity.DeEntitize
- HttpUtility.HtmlDecode
- WebUtility.HtmlDecode

For example, when I like to decode **`Martian&amp;#039;s atmosphere`**, I get **`Martian&#039;s atmosphere`** instead of **`Martian's atmosphere`**.

And When I use this code (for exp), all is right (characters are decoded):

```
    TextBox1.Text = "Martian&amp;#039;s atmosphere"
    For i = 0 To 2
        TextBox1.Text = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(TextBox1.Text)
        i += 1
    Next
```

The problem is I don't like to use loops, because sometimes I have to decode a full HTML page or long texts.

Comment: So you're saying you have to run the string through HtmlDecode twice before it's fully decoded?

Comment: `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` Seems to work: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CVJUxQ

Comment: Yes. I have to run HtmlDecode more. If a single word has 3 encoded entities, I have to run HtmlDecode 3 times.

Comment: @David McLean I tried just now your example in my Visual Studio, without a succes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have any way of knowing in advance how many times a string will need to be decoded until you get the result you want, so you're going to have to use either a loop or recursion to get the desired result.  Here's a recursive function to do it:

```
function DecodeUntilUnchanged(string str)
{
    string decoded = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(str);
    if(decoded == str)
       return str;
    return DecodeUntilUnchanged(decoded);
}
```

You'd use it like this:

```
TextBox1.Text = DecodeUntilUnchanged(TextBox1.Text);
```

Comment: Thank you @Dave. It's exactly what I want. And your code works.
But, I want to know why **WebUtility.HtmlDecode** does not decode the whole word.

Comment: It really depends on where you're getting those strings in the first place.  It sounds like you've got something that's escaping `'` as `&#39;` and then escaping that `&` as `&amp;`